# How do I create a second primary key/compound key in mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I have a table called `enrollments` that looks like this:

```
enrollmentindex - which is table primary key
username - varchar(64)
shortname - varchar(64)
role - varcar(64)
```

I have to leave the `enrollmentindex` col, but would like to create a second `primary key` (compound key) using `username`, `shortname` and `role`.

I am having trouble creating the new compound key because of the existence of the key on `enrollmentindex`.

**Tried:**

```
ALTER TABLE enrollments ADD PRIMARY KEY(username,shortname,role)
```

-- results in error code `1068`.

```
ALTER TABLE enrollments DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(username,shortname,role)
```

-- results in error code `1075`

There is no data in the table.

Comment: Any reason you need to have a compound primary key like this? Should probably create a natural key for the PK, and create a UNIQUE index for username, shortname, role, instead

Comment: The second `ALTER` command should work. Which version of `MySQL` are you using? And, as suggested by Noah, a `unique index` is a better option.

Comment: 5.3.13.  The UNIQUE INDEX for those fields, rather than a primary key, was the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Code 1068 is for Multiple Primary Keys (not allowed)

Error Code 1075 is for Incorrect Table Definition (auto_increment fields must be defined as a key). It looks like enrollmentindex is an auto_increment field, so it will need to be included in your composite primary key.

I would suggest creating a separate UNIQUE index on `username,shortname,role`, if that's something you want to force

Comment: Thank you, the UNIQUE index, not another primary key, was the ticket.